# Azure Entra ID Authentication Requiring Admin Consent

Tags: azure, authentication, microsoft-entra-id

I have a web app service for which I am trying to configure Azure Entra ID authentication. The issue I'm having is I am able to log in, but other users are not. They continually receive "Admin consent is required for the permissions requested by this application. An admin consent request may be sent to the admin." However, none of the permissions set require admin consent.

I have the ability to create application registrations in Entra ID, and I've recreated the app registration several times. However, I do not have specific permissions to change the enterprise app settings.

These first screenshots are of the app registration authentication settings.

[image: App Registration Authentication]
[image: App Registration Authentication]

Next are the assigned API permissions
[image]

That is it as far as the app registration is concerned.

As for the authentication settings for the app service, they are shown here
[image]

I've searched and read through a number of similar questions here on SO, such as [Azure AD admin consent required when it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081476/azure-ad-admin-consent-required-when-it-shouldnt) and [Azure AD authentication access without admin consent to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74791974/azure-ad-authentication-access-without-admin-consent-to-application). The answers to these questions do not help. As you can see, I don't have permission/authorization to provide admin consent for the organization.
[image]

The same is true for the enterprise application. All settings are disabled for the application in the Self-Service blade.

[image]

And I do not have any permissions that require admin consent.

[image]
[image]

In adding the app registration, I've followed [Configure your App Service or Azure Functions app to use Microsoft Entra sign-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad?tabs=workforce-tenant#advanced) as well as [Quickstart: Register an application with the Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-register-app).

Is there a way to solve this, or do I have to go back to my Entra admins and ask them to change something?

Comment: There is a tenant-wide setting that makes all permissions require admin consent, regardless if the permission requires it or not.

Comment: @juunas, what is this tenant-wide setting? Plus I do *NOT* want to require admin consent. It is not necessary for this application. Maybe I misread your comment?

Comment: Rukmini's answer shows the setting :) Yeah, it's tenant-wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a **Microsoft Entra ID application** and added API permissions like below:

[image]

Created **Web app** added authentication as Microsoft, selected the above Microsoft Entra application:

[image]

For ***sample***, I used the below endpoint to authorize the users:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://rukweb.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

**Got the same error as below:**

[image]

**The error usually occurs** if the API permissions granted to the Microsoft Entra ID is not granted admin consent or the user consent is not enabled in the tenant.

*In your scenario,* as you do not want to grant the admin consent, you can contact the Global Admin to set the changes in Enterprise applications blade like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise application -> Consent and permissions -> User consent settings -> Enable the option Allow user consent for apps -> Save***

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can enable **"*Allow user consent for apps from verified publishers, for selected permissions option*"**:

[image]

And for the above option to work, you need to add **`user.read`** API permission in the permission classifications blade:

[image]

**Now I am able to sign in successfully like below:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I have tried adding API permissions to no avail. So I believe I need to go to our global admin and ask them to change settings.

Comment: Absolutely. This answer will be accepted, provided it works.